# How to import a Text file content to a JTextArea in a Java application?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, import, jtextarea

how to import a Text file content to a JTextArea in a Java application using JFileChooser?

Comment: You must be in the military, nice command. Anyways what have you tried? Doesn't look like you have tried it at all.

Comment: @mwdar: next time try it yourself and include your problematic code in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

should be something like the following code:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null); //replace null with your swing container
File file;
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)     
  file = chooser.getSelectedFile();    
}

JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = in.readLine();
while(line != null){
  text.append(line + "\n");
  line = in.readLine();
}
```

The basic logic:

```java
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = in.readLine();
while(line != null){
  text.append(line + "\n");
  line = in.readLine();
}
```

Comment: -1, yes I know this works. But I tend to down vote solutions that reinvent the wheel. All text components support a read(...) method which should be used.

Comment: My proposal was to use the read(..) method. I voted it down because this was the accepted answer and I don't want people who search the forum and find this answer to use it.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Document Viewer]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;

class DocumentViewer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JFrame f = new JFrame("Document Viewer");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

                final JEditorPane document = new JEditorPane();
                gui.add(new JScrollPane(document), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JButton open = new JButton("Open");
                open.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(f);
                        if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                            try {
                                document.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                gui.add(open, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                f.setContentPane(gui);
                f.pack();
                f.setSize(400,300);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To import the contents of a file into a JTextArea you simply follow these steps!

1. Create a frame and add a JTextArea to it.
2. You declare and initialize a JFileChooser.
3. You add a listener to the JFileChooser.
4. In your actionPerformed, you should take the file that was selected and pass it to a method  that would read this file(see NB below).
5. In that method, you open a file reader and read the contents of the file, line by line. As you do so, you append each line to the JTextArea.
6. When you get to the end of the file, you close the file reader.
7. Run the program and you should be good to go.

The above steps are good enough to perform your task. However, when you give it a try, i would edit my post and add a possible solution.

NB: You must note that when you select a file with a JFileChooser, it returns an Object of type File. You should then use the `getName()` method provided by the File class to get the name of the file.

Links that might be of help!
[JFileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)
[File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)
[Java tutorials on how to use the JFileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Answer (score 1):

Determine the filename given from the FileChooser, read the contents of the file into a String (e.g. using a [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)), set the contents of the JTextArea to the contents of the buffer using [`JTextField#setText(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
     final JEditorPane document = new JEditorPane();
    int returnval=jf.showDialog(this, null);
    File file = null;
    if(returnval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)     
     file = jf.getSelectedFile(); 
    String str ;
    try {
        byte bt[]= Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());   
        str=new String(bt,"UTF-8");
        System.out.println(str);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```