# How to get the contains of file in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I create a jtable like this :

[image]

```
String name = temp.getName();
String enemy = namaFileUtama.toString(); 
DefaultTableModel models = (DefaultTableModel) Main_Menu.jTable4.getModel();
            List<ReportMomentOfTruth> theListRMOT = new ArrayList<ReportMomentOfTruth>();
            ReportMomentOfTruth rmot = new ReportMomentOfTruth();
            rmot.setNameOfMainFile(name);
            rmot.setNameOfComparingFile(enemy);
            theListRMOT.add(rmot);

            for (ReportMomentOfTruth reportMomentOfTruth : theListRMOT) {
                models.addRow(new Object[]{
                    reportMomentOfTruth.getNamaFileUtama(),
                    reportMomentOfTruth.getNamaFilePembanding(),
                });
            }
```

You know, I dont get an idea. How can I get the contains the file if I click one row in jtable then the contains will be show in jTextArea ? Any suggestion ? any example perhaps ?
Thanks

```
edit
```

You know, I am using netbeans, I can get a method like this

```
private void jTable4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if (evt.getClickCount() == 1) {

    }
}
```

Now how to ?

Comment: You want to display a file content in one column of JTable or want to display content in JTextArea got from one column of JTable.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get the contains the file if I click one row in jtable then the contains will be show in jTextArea?

You can better use [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) that has a method [`setPage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setPage%28java.lang.String%29) that can be used to initialize the component from a URL.

Just get the values of selected row and use below code to set the content in `JEditorPane`.

sample code:

```
final JEditorPane document = new JEditorPane();
document.setPage(new File(".../a.java").toURI().toURL());
```

---

Add `ListSelectionListener` to detect the selection change event in the `JTable`

```
final JTable jTable = new JTable();
jTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
jTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
      int row = jTable.getSelectedRow();
      if(row != -1){
         String firstColumnValue = jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
         String secondColumnValue = jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
         // load the JEditorPane
      }
    }
});;
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033589/how-to-import-a-text-file-content-to-a-jtextarea-in-a-java-application)

Comment: All JTExtComponents support a `read(...)` method. Just use the read() method to populate your JTextArea. A JEditorPane is used to display HTML.

Comment: @camickr thanks it's a good option. I never noticed it before.

Comment: @camickr , can U give me an example ?

Comment: @user2971238 follow the Java Doc.